# How can I query data from nested collections in Expo from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

[This is the document structure][1] I need to get data from nested collection (journal/userID/entries) in Firestore into a Flatlist (React Native/Expo). Here is my code snippet:

```
function TextEntry() {
  const ref =
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('journal')
      .doc(currentUserUID)
      .collection('entry')

  useEffect(() => {
    return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const list = [];
      console.log(currentUserUID)
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const { title } = doc.data()
        list.push({
          id: doc.id,
          title,
        });
      });

      setTodos(list);

      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  let currentUserUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  async function addTodo() {
    await ref.add({
      title: todo,
    });
    setTodo('');
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you shared? If you step through it in the debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks Frank!

The code doesn't break but it does not return documents from the nested collection (i.e. entry).

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. If you put a breakpoint on `const list = []` and run in a debugger, does it reach that breakpoint? If it does and you then step through the code, does it go into the `forEach`? If not, can you log the value of `currentUserUID`, and include the updated code, its output, and a screenshot of a document you'd expect to be returned into the question (there's an `edit` link right under it for this purpose)?

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank!  We reach the first breakpoint, we don't get into forEach loop. The currentUserUID(OeOfQKULcXYV15UlgrySb5rj5qt1) returns the expected value of the logged in user. But it differs from the document id created in the Firestore. I've updated the code, to include the section where the section of the code where it creates the document where I imagine the problem is, link for screenshot is above.

Comment: So it sounds like the current user (`OeOfQKULcXYV15UlgrySb5rj5qt1`) doesn't have any entries in the database.

Comment: The current user does have entries the problem is that, I expect the document to have the  (OeOfQKULcXYV15UlgrySb5rj5qt1) id, but firestore generates it's own id for the document, I'm able to successfully save entries in the database, but I can't return the entry.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks a lot for the help, the issue had to do with the userID after all.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem @nikita6120 